# Make dialog appear after listview item button click

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have an application loads a listview based on a database query. In each listview item there is a text view and a few buttons. So I have created a custom adapter. My issue is that I am trying to make a dialog appear when a button in the listview it clicked but I dont know how to call the fragment manager from the listview adapter.

DanceAdapter.java

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final OneDancer oneDancer = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
                //Sign-In Activity
            if(type==1) {


            }else if (type==2)
            {

                Log.v("DancerAdapter","item_dj_dancer Loaded");

            }
            //VIP/Dances Adapter
            else if(type==3) {

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_services, parent, false);

                final Button button4 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);

                final TextView counterTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);

                final Button button6 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button6);



                button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        DialogFragment newFragment = new SignInActivity.ConfirmDancerDialog();
                        newFragment.show(new getFragmentManager(), "Dancer Confirmed");

                        button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        counterTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });




            }

        }
```

Here is the code for the method in the activity that populates the listview.

Services. java

```
// Parsing of dancers

public void parseDancerList(String response) {

Log.v("SignInActivity","parseDancerList");
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

Document doc = parser.getDomElement(response); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("DANCERS");

DancerAdapter adapter = new DancerAdapter(this,oneDancerArrayList,3);

Log.v("response ", "Dancer Count " + nl.getLength());
// looping through all item nodes <item>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap

    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    Log.v("response ", "Dancers  " + parser.getValue(e, "NAME"));

    OneDancer newDancer = new OneDancer(parser.getValue(e,"POSITION"),
            parser.getValue(e,"NAME"),
            parser.getValue(e,"AVAILABLE"),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    adapter.addAll(newDancer);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




}
```

}

Comment: pardon me, but I kinda didn't fully get what you mean, why you want to access fragment manager? If you want an instance of "AlertDialog" you need a context only, you can pass it in constructor of your adapter.

Comment: Forgive my ignorace. I was coping code from another area in my app that displays a dialog. However its being called directly from the activity. Can show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: np :), I've added something, check it out, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess it's just that you are tired that you didn't realize how to do this, cuz it's simple really, atleast if I'm not missing something and I'm not tired myself xd. here's the code:

in activity:

```
DancerAdapter adapter = new DancerAdapter(this,oneDancerArrayList,3, getSupportFragmentManager());
```

in your DancerAdapter:

```
private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public DancerAdapter(...,FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    ...
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;//now you have a reference to it
}
```

Comment: That was simple. Thank you!

Comment: yw, as I said it was just matter of being tired, I'm sure you knew it yourself :)